# Get authenticated user details from a remote database

Tags: 7

I have 2 domains say `site1.com` and `example.com`. I have separate `databases` for both these sites .

How could I perform or allow users from my `site1.com` to login to my second site `example.com` without registering. If a person is an `authenticated user` in `site1.com`, he or she could login to the `example.com` site without `signing up`, i.e by using the login credentials of `site1.com`. Are there any modules that would help or be suitable for my task?

Also I would like to know is I could access some `table` details from a `remote database`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend separating these questions.

1) Drupal Single Sign on module: https://drupal.org/project/sso

2) Again, I recommend posting this as a separate question, but could you be more specific? which table(s)?

Comment: tanx for the reply @jdu.But i really need it for my drupal 7 website.`sso` is for drupal 6